# How can I display Hijri Calender instead of Georgian Calender in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, calendar, hijri

As the question above, how can I display Hijri Calendar instead of Georgian Calendar.

I tried to do, but there is no property for Hijri in MonthCalendar.

Comment: I don't think it is available out of the box but you can use [this control](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23226/Windows-Hijri-Calendar).

Comment: have you tried using [HijriCalendar Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.hijricalendar?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't, cuz I'm beginner